# Is there a way to increase the contrast of the special highlighting that is applied to the OP of a question?

Tags: feature-request, javascript, greasemonkey

**EDIT**: as you can see, the OP is now highlighted a bit more clearly, in 2021! But this may change, or someone might want a more striking contrast.

---

When the Original Poster of a question comments somewhere on the question page, his name is sort of highlighted:

[image]

Here it was Mitch (in case you didn't notice), who had asked for a female equivalent to *guys* on English.SE.

I can hardly spot the difference on my monitor; I've tried changing the contrast, but it remains very subtle. I often miss it.

Is there any Greasemonkey script that somehow increases the visibility of this "OP" highlighting? Or is there some other way to do it? Sadly, I can hardly program at all, and I couldn't write a single line in Javascript if my life depended on it, or I'd create a GM script this instant. I live at [english.stackexchange.com](http://english.stackexchange.com), so I'm looking for a solution that would work there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was even easier than I thought. Here is what you'll see after installing it:

---

[image]

---

You can download the script by clicking here:

http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/userscripts/owner.user.js

Please let me know if it works!

Comment: @Cer: No problem. Glad it worked.

Comment: I hate to bother you with this, but... your (great!) highlighting gets replaced by the original when an abridged list of comments is expanded. You will see what I mean when you click the "show all comments" below this question: [What the British say vs. What the British mean](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28538/what-the-british-say-vs-what-the-british-mean) Do you think it would be complicated to circumvent this?

Comment: @Cer: *[Slaps forehead]*... I totally forgot about that. Let me see if I can fix that. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Cer: ...and **done!** Please let me know if it fixes the problem. The download link for the update is the same.

Comment: Thanks, but, alas, the new version doesn't do anything for me. It is active on english.se.com, but the highlighting is now always in the original format, whether expanded or not.. I have tried disabling all other userscripts, but in vain. I am using Firefox. Would be great if you could fix it! // The asker of the example question above has sadly been chased away in the meantime and so lost his highlighting, but here is another question with expandable comments to test on: [Good movies for learning English](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7476/good-movies-for-learning-english)

Comment: @Cer: Once again, sorry about that! I have fixed it now and tested it in Firefox this time. Same download link.

Comment: Perfect! It works on any page I throw at it now. Your code looks well commented (though I'm not a good judge). I am forever in your debt.